# inserting multiple rows with one insert command

Tags: sql, oracle

Is it possible to insert more than one row in a table with one insert statement?
I know this will happen if I do:

```
insert into table ( fields ) select values from another_table
```

But what if I want to insert:

```
row 1 - ( a1, b1, c1 )
row 2 - ( a2, b2, c2 )
...
row n - ( an, bn, cn )
```

with just one insert command?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Two solutions (source : http://appsfr.free.fr/spip.php?article21 ):

```
INSERT ALL
INTO table (column1, column2)
VALUES (value1, value2)
INTO table (column1, column2)
VALUES (value1, value2)
...etc...
SELECT * FROM DUAL ;
```

or

```
INSERT INTO table (column1, column2)
SELECT value1, value2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT value1, value2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
...etc...
SELECT value1, value2 FROM DUAL ;
```

Answer (score 5):

[Insert All](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/questions/insert_rows.php)

```
INSERT ALL
   INTO mytable (column1, column2, column3) VALUES ('val1.1', 'val1.2', 'val1.3')
   INTO mytable (column1, column2, column3) VALUES ('val2.1', 'val2.2', 'val2.3')
   INTO mytable (column1, column2, column3) VALUES ('val3.1', 'val3.2', 'val3.3')
SELECT * FROM dual;
```

Answer (score 3):

```
INSERT INTO products (product_no, name, price) VALUES
    (1, 'Cheese', 9.99),
    (2, 'Bread', 1.99),
    (3, 'Milk', 2.99);
```

Comment: The question is for oracle so why are you posting a PostgreSQL answer?

Comment: I removed 'PostgreSQL' in my answer. For your info, this is standard SQL-92.

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO College (CustomerID, FirstName, MiddleName, LastName)

SELECT 7, N'Charles', N'Simmons', N'Burns'
UNION ALL
SELECT 9, N'Dominic', N'Fred', N'Einsten'
UNION ALL
SELECT 12, N'Dave', N'William, N'Bryan';
```

**NOTE:**
Letter N before each hard coded string value converts string to an NVARCHAR value to match the datatype of the column.

Answer (score -5):

No, this is not possible. As you already stated yourself, it is only possible with a select clause providing the insert values and rows.

Comment: at least after reading the accepted answer along with some other given, you definitely know now that it is possible.